# Instalation of Xamarin in Pc with AMD processor

Tags: xamarin, amd-processor

I installed Xamarin on a PC with an AMD Processor (tested with AMD A10 8700P), the installation process occurred without problems,  but - in the moment of the execution - Xamarin is not shown. Is it possible to install Xamarin with this type of processor? I installed Xamarin on a PC with Intel processor and had no problems.

Comment: What is not shown? The emulator, something else? It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Not shown the IDE